# Count of working workers less then maximum pool size

Tags: php, amphp

Good day. I use amphp parallel-functions. I set the maximum pool size to 128 - the number of workers is stable at 128.
I set it to 256 - I get different values for the number of working workers from launch to launch. But always less than the maximum value. What does it depend on?

Comment: I think it's limited by the amount of memory available. Each worker takes up a certain amount and at some point you've run out of memory to spend, thus no more workers can be created.

Comment: @PtrTon This doesn't sound like a memory problem. It's more than enough.